# Remove Vowel Runs in Python

Tags: python

So I am fairly new to python and I am stuck on a question. Basically, I need to create a function {remove_vowels_runs(message, n):} which takes the arguments message, and {n}. The {message} is any string of text and the {n} marks how many times it will allow the string to contain consecutive vowels.

So far, I've tried nesting loops and importing functions but I run into the same problem which is that I modify the length and content of message while it is iterating so inevitably, at some point, my list index is out of range.

Here is what I have so far.

```
def remove_vowels_runs(message, n):
vowels = ['a', 'A', 'e', 'E', 'i', 'I', 'o', 'O', 'u', 'U']
message = list(message)
list_length = len(message)
run = 0
for i in range(list_length):
i = int(i)
x = message[i]
if x not in vowels and run == n:
    run -= run
elif x not in vowels:
    run -= run
elif x in vowels and run <= n:
    run += 1
if run > n:
    message.remove(message[i])
    run -= run
    i -= i

return ''.join(message)
print(remove_vowels_runs('aeiou', 3))
```

and I also have:

```
def remove_vowel_runs(message, n):
    message = list(message)
    string_length = len(message)
    for i in range(string_length):
        remove_n_vowels(message, i, n)
        return ''.join(message)


def remove_n_vowels(message, j, k):
    x = message[j]
    vowels = ['a', 'A', 'e', 'E', 'i', 'I', 'o', 'O', 'u', 'U']
    run = 1
    p = j+1
    while (run <= k) and (x in vowels):
        x = message[p]
        if x in vowels and run <= k:
            run += 1
            p += 1
        if x in vowels and run > k:
            message.remove(x)
        elif x not in vowels and run == k:
            run -= run
        elif x not in vowels and run != k:
            run -= run
    return x
```

Basically the problem is that I need to delete the vowels only if it is placed consecutively after whatever value the argument n is and that is really the crux of my problem. I've been at this question for 3 hours and I am ready to pull my hair out. Please help if you are a kind soul.

Here are some of the expected results from an input -

Function call: remove_vowel_runs(’Stony Brook University’, 2)

Return value: ’Stony Brook University’

Function call: remove_vowel_runs(’aeiou’, 3)

Return value: 'aei'

Function call: remove_vowel_runs('Stony Brook University', 0)

Return value: 'Stny Brook nvrsty'

Comment: Can you update the question, with possible input and output? That will make more understanding.

Comment: Yes. Since I cannot find an attachment link to the pdf, I will post some input and output examples.

Comment: I just added a few input and outputs on my post because it wont let me do it here

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple serious flaws with your code.

- `message.remove(message[i])` removes *all* elements equal to `message[i]`, not just the one at position `i`. If you want to remove just that one, you do `del message[i]`.
- Every time you remove anything from `message`, everything after the removed character shifts one slot to the left. So, let's say `i` is 3, and remove element #3. Then element #4 shifts over to slot #3, and #5 shifts over to #4, and so on. And then, next time through the loop, `i` is 4, so you look at the new #4. That means you entirely missed the original #4, and won't count it.
- Every time you remove something from `message`, it gets smaller. But you already calculated `len` before the list ever started. So, let's say you have 6 letters, and you remove #3. Then you look at #4. Then you look at #5… oops, there is no #5 anymore; the list ends at #4, so you get an `IndexError`.

The simplest way to fix all of these problems in one fell swoop is to not try to modify `message`. Instead, build up a new list, adding the letters from `message` that you want to keep, while skipping the ones you don't.

---

There are probably other bugs in your code, but it's hard to be sure. For example, consider this:

```
if x not in vowels and run == n:
    run -= run
elif x not in vowels:
    run -= run
```

In the `if x not in vowels and run == n` case, you do the same thing as in the `elif x not in vowels:` case. Presumably, if that's what you wanted, you wouldn't have bothered with two separate cases; you'd just do `if x not in vowels:`. So you must have intended this distinction to serve some purpose… but it's hard to guess what that purpose is.

Also, that `i -= 1` has no effect, because it's at the end of a `for` loop where `i` is the loop variable, so it's just going to be immediately reassigned. It looks like maybe you wanted to repeat the last letter, as the start of a new run, in this case, but that doesn't make sense, so… what *were* you trying to do there? Why are you doing `run -= run` instead of just `run = 0`? That's strange enough to make me think you must have intended something more than setting it to 0… but again, I can't guess what it is that you intended. Or, why `i = int(i)`? Did you think it was some other type besides an `int`, or were you trying to do something else here, or…?

---

If you fix all of that, you get a function that doesn't raise an `IndexError`, and does something sort of close to what you wanted, but still not correct:

```
def remove_vowels_runs(message, n):
    vowels = ['a', 'A', 'e', 'E', 'i', 'I', 'o', 'O', 'u', 'U']
    result = []
    run = 0
    for x in message:        
        if x not in vowels:
            run = 0
            result.append(x)
        elif run <= n:
            run += 1
            result.append(x)
        else:
            run = 0
    return ''.join(result)
```

But maybe that's enough for you to figure out the next step from there?

Comment: okay so I did what you suggested. I created an empty list but now my problem is how to tell my code to allow more than n vowels as long as it is not consecutive. for instance, 'Stony Brook University' has 7 vowels in it but if 'n' is 2, then it has to delete every 3rd vowel that follows after 2 previous letters that are both vowels. Therefore, the function would return exactly the same string it was given. I can sift out vowels but they are fixed to only n and any vowels that are found after n gets passed. Any tips?

Comment: @SeungsooIm Your code (after the fixes) is already kind of doing that, it's just got a bunch of the details wrong. To start with, you're using `<=` instead of `<`. You're also setting the `run` back to 0 as soon as you drop a vowel so the next one starts a new run, which is obviously wrong. And probably more problems besides. I'm not going to find every logic error in your code and fix them all for you, much less throw away your code and write working code. You need to learn how to (a) think through your logic, and (b) debug your code and see what it's doing at each step.

Comment: I fixed it but your suggestions went a long way. Thank you anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I finally figured it out. Instead of trying to modify a list while it is iterating, I created an empty list and assigned boolean values to the original list and then I append the original to the new list depending on their boolean values. Here is my code:

```
def remove_vowel_runs(message, n):
vowels = ['a', 'A', 'e', 'E', 'i', 'I', 'o', 'O', 'u', 'U']
message = list(message)
message_length = len(message)
new_msg = []
run = 0

for i in range(message_length):
    if (run < n) and (message[i] in vowels):
        run += 1
    elif (run >= n) and (message[i] in vowels):
        message[i] = False
    elif i not in vowels:
        run = 0
for j in range(message_length):
    if message[j] is not False:
        new_msg.append(message[j])
return ''.join(new_msg)
```